# How to test if Graphics card is causing freezes

Tags: intel-graphics

My ubuntu 12.04 distro often freezes when for example watching a youtube video.

My system is a 15,6 inch BTO VBOOK 15CL17 FULL HD IPS with a Intel HD Graphics 4600.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphic
```

After a crash my dmesg.log looks like this: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7010739/

and my lshw output is as follows:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7010769/

How can I test if my graphics driver is causing this problem?

Comment: This is neither a duplicate of "What should I do when Ubuntu freezes" nor is off-topic with the information provided by the OP. It asks how to test the graphics drivers to see if it is involved in the freezing problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would first recommend installing `sensord` to test the temperature of various hardware devices (CPU for example):

```
sudo apt-get install sensord
```

After that simply run `sensors` to get a reading. It should look something like this:

[image]

If you can get to the desktop somehow (Or change to another desktop or even run an LiveCD or LiveUSB image to test the hardware) you can install `psensors`

[image]

or from the Panel

[image]

You can also check the Hard Drive temperature with `hddtemp` just in case it is also affecting the freezing problem:

[image]

Lastly there is another GUI app called i-nex which is first added to Ubuntu via a PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository nex-development-team/stable
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

Then simply run i-nex:

[image]

As you can see there are a couple of ways of checking the integrated video card, PCIe video card of even the CPU and HDD for temperature readings.

I would also recommend checking in your laptop/motherboard site if they have an updated firmware. In my case I was having a similar problem when using 3D with the HD card until I updated the firmware.

Another upgrade I recommend is to either apply the Xorg Edgers PPA or the Intel Graphics installer Update:

Intel Graphics Installer - https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ - Simply download the appropriate driver package and install. You can also find the changelog in there.

Xorg Edgers PPA - Run the following 3 lines and then reboot to see the enhancements:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should leave you with an updated Mesa, Intel drivers and a couple of more things as shown in the Xorg PPA site.

So you have various alternatives to check and update the system.

Comment: Thanks a million, The problem seemed to be solved by the Xorg Edgers PPA upgrade. However I could not add the nex-development-team/stable repository. At the moment that is not required since the problem seemed to be solved. If it haunts me again I will try the other tips. Also for the hardware temperatures I obtain values between 14 and 41 degrees for different components. But I am not sure what values would be alarming here.